# Julia, ArchGDAL installation error on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, runtime-error, julia

I'm very new to Julia and tried to implement the code provided [here](http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/julia-prt1/). I succeeded in installing all packages listed there, except for ArchGDAL, which only yields error.

I have been googleing for a while, but I was unable to find a solution. I'm running Julia 1.2.0.

```
julia> Pkg.add("ArchGDAL")
```

I get the following error. Can anybody help me to find a solution to this problem?

```
Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package ArchGDAL [c9ce4bd3]:
 ArchGDAL [c9ce4bd3] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0, 0.2.0-0.2.1] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.1.0, 0.2.0-0.2.1]
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with GDAL [add2ef01] to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
   └─GDAL [add2ef01] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0-0.1.2, 0.2.0, 1.0.0-1.0.1] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions 1.0.1 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that GDAL.jl tagged a 1.0 release, which changed from the GDAL 2 to GDAL 3 API.  In addition to this, several function names have been changed.  Therefore, it seems the maintainers of ArchGDAL (@yeesian) decided to pin the compatible GDAL version at 0.2.1 (the last release before 1.0).

Because you have GDAL.jl explicitly installed, Pkg will not change its version.  What you have to do is this:

```
using Pkg
pkg"rm GDAL" # remove GDAL from your Project.toml
pkg"add ArchGDAL; add GDAL"
```